# Java Swing Validation Issue - "Interface Expected Here"

Tags: java

I am trying to create a registration form using JAVA Swing in NetBeans 6.5. I have created the form however I keep getting the "Interface Expected Here" error in the following line:

```
public class CustomPasswordMatchStringValidator implements StringValidator<String>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong all it does is it validates the string provided by the user. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have provided a part of my code below:

```
package com.forms;
    
    import java.awt.Cursor;
    import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import org.netbeans.validation.api.Problem;
    import org.netbeans.validation.api.Problems;
    import org.netbeans.validation.api.builtin.stringvalidation.StringValidators;
    import org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.ValidationGroup;
    import org.openide.util.Exceptions;
    import com.dao.UserDAO;
    
    import com.helper.GetSetProperties;
    import com.helper.SimpleCrypto;
    
    //import swinghelper.SwingUtilities;
    
    /**
     *
     * @author admin
     */
    public class RegistrationForm extends javax.swing.JFrame
    {
     ValidationGroup vg;
        /** Creates new form RegistrationForm */
        public RegistrationForm()
        {
            initComponents();
                 // swinghelper.SwingUtilities.setScreenCenter(this);
                btnUpdate.setVisible(false);
                      vg= validationPanel1.getValidationGroup();
           //vg.add(jTextField1, ValidationStrategy.DEFAULT, null)
     vg.add(txtFName,  StringValidators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING,
              StringValidators.NO_WHITESPACE);
     vg.add(txtLName,  StringValidators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING,
              StringValidators.NO_WHITESPACE);
     
      vg.add(txtCellNo, StringValidators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING,
              StringValidators.minLength(10));
    
      vg.add(txtEmailAddr, StringValidators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING,
              StringValidators.EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    
        vg.add(txtLoginId, StringValidators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING,
              StringValidators.NO_WHITESPACE);
     
          vg.add(jPasswordField1, StringValidators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING,
              StringValidators.NO_WHITESPACE);
          vg.add(jPasswordField2, StringValidators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING,
              StringValidators.NO_WHITESPACE);
              vg.add(txtEmailAddr1, StringValidators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING,
              StringValidators.NO_WHITESPACE);
    
           vg.add(txtEmailAddr2, StringValidators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING,
              StringValidators.NO_WHITESPACE);
    
                  vg.add(jPasswordField2, new CustomPasswordMatchStringValidator());
            try
            {
                this.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/img/Accept-Male-User128.png")));
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
            }
    
        }
              public class CustomPasswordMatchStringValidator implements StringValidator<String>
            {
            
    
            public boolean validate(Problems problems, String compName, String model)
            {
    
                boolean result = jPasswordField1.getText().equals(jPasswordField2.getText());
                if (!result)
                {
                    String message = "Password and confirm password do not match!";
                    problems.add(message);
                }
                return result;
    
            }
    
        }
        public static boolean FLAG = true;
        UserDAO userdao = new UserDAO();
```

Comment: What even is validationPanel1 and could you provide the entire error log?

Comment: You are also missing an end bracket at the end of your class and:
public static boolean FLAG = true;
UserDAO userdao = new UserDAO(); is not inside any method

Comment: From which library do you import `StringValidator`? I could not find this interface anywhere

Comment: I actually figured it out thanks alll!

Comment: Great! It would be even better if you could write down your solution as an answer to this question (so you or anyone else could find the solution in the future)